# Why can't I seem to use qi locals as the semantic predicate to eps?

Tags: boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

When using `qi::locals`, a local parameter doesn't seem like it can be used as the semantic predicate to `eps`.  Here is a stripped down fictional example:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
using namespace qi::labels;
using qi::eps;

template <typename Iterator, typename Any>
struct parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, Any(), qi::locals<bool> > {
    parser() : parser::base_type(p) {
        p = eps[_a=false] >> eps(_a);
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, Any(), qi::locals<bool> > p;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int val;
    std::string data;
    auto i = data.cbegin();
    auto end = data.cend();
    parser<decltype(i), decltype(val) > p;
    bool rv = phrase_parse(i, end, p, ascii::blank, val);
    return rv ? 0 : 1;
}
```

In this example, if I remove the `(_a)` after the second `eps`, everything compiles cleanly.  With the `(_a)`, I get a morass of failed template instantiation.  The context doesn't matter, as I have solved this problem in my real code-base another way, but I would like to know why this does not work.

Comment: Why don't you specify which compiler/boost version you're using. +1 for excellent minimal self contained sample though

Comment: g++ 4.9.2, boost 1.55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my compilers/boost versions it works See also **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d33beec2e7efbf8d)**

On a whim I'm suspecting bugs that have crept into the "old" Phoenix V2 implementation. Phoenix V2 was still a part of the Spirit Library technically. It has been superseded by Phoenix V3 which lives as the separate library in `boost/phoenx/...`.

Boost Phoenix V2 is showing cracks of age - mainly on modern compilers where the BOOST_RESULT_OF() utilities use `decltype`.

Long story short

1. try using

   ```
    #define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
   ```

   to use it iff your compiler/boost combination doesn't select it.¹
2. inversely, if your compiler is oldish, try

   ```
   #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1
   ```

---

¹ Recent Spirit versions dropped Phoenix V2 : **[Farewell Phoenix-v2](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2013/12/13/farewell-phoenix-2/)**